# Download a webpage in pdf format using angular4

Tags: angular, webpack-2, jspdf, html2canvas, typescript2.4

I am new for angular 4. I need to download a HTML webpage in pdf format and the html webpage contains angular controls like input **[(ngModel)]**, radio button  **[checked]**. 
Rather than showing the control values it shows **undefined** in the pdf file.

I tried using **jsPdf & html2Pdf** But it throws error

**Error:**

```
You need either https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas or https://github.com/cburgmer/rasterizeHTML.js
    at Object.jsPDFAPI.addHTML (jspdf.debug.js?6964:4049)
```

**Code for TS File:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Compiler, ComponentRef, OnInit, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
    import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas';


    @Component({
        templateUrl: "./dashboard.html"
    })

    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
     ngOnInit() {

        }


        pdf() {
            let pdf = new jsPDF();
            let options = {
                pagesplit: true
            };
            pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("htmlform"), 0, 0, options, () => {
                pdf.save("test.pdf");
            });
        }
    }
```

**Code for HTML**

```
<div>
<button type="button" (click)="pdf()"></button>
</div>
<ng-component>
<html id="htmlform">
<head>
DashBoard
</head>
<body>
<h3>
Person Details
</h3>
<table>
  <tbody>
 <tr class="BorderTopSec">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="label">
                        &nbsp;NAME:
                    </div>
                    <input name="person_name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.Name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td rowspan="4" style="border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: black black black white; width: 164px;">
                    <img height="150" id="imgPhoto" src="" width="155" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>
                    <div class="label">
                        &nbsp;LOCATION:
                    </div>
                    <select name="LOCATION" style="border: currentColor; width: 95px; font-size: 13px;" [(ngModel)]="model.location">
                        <option *ngFor="let item of model.location" [ngValue]="locationId">{{item.location}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>
                    <div class="label">
                        &nbsp;SEX:
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                <md-radio-group>
  <md-radio-button value="1"   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" >Option 1</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button value="2" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" >Option 2</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
                </td>

</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

</body>
</html>
</ng-component>
```

Comment: `html2canvas` is not included properly.
you can try using it in `index.html` `<script></script>`

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya without including the html2canvas script can we download the html in  pdf format

Comment: @Vignesh if designing is important for you of html then use html2canvas, otherwise with normal design like tables you can use `pdfmake`

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya can we import html2canvas in vendor file and we can access the file in all components right

Comment: @Vignesh I've added it in index.html and then `declare let html2pdf;` in whatever component

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya can we import any external js script files from particular folder to index.html

Comment: @Vignesh Yes, Of course

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya i have added js files in asserts folder and while calling that script in index.html in throws following error net::ERR_ABORTED error  <script src="asset/script.js"></script>

Comment: @Vignesh check for the correct path

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya i have changed the path to "<script src="src/app/asset/jquery.min.js"></script>" it worked fine after taking build and publishing in production it's throwing 404 error

Comment: @Vignesh add it like `<script src="./asset/script.js">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158930/discussion-between-vignesh-and-nikhil-radadiya).

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya i am getting error GET http://localhost:xxxx/asset/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya <script src="src/app/asset/jquery.min.js"></script> it's working fine after taking build it's throwing 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You need to globally import the `/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.min.js` script, you can do it like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855891/angular-cli-webpack-how-to-add-or-bundle-external-js-files#answer-39661714) and documented [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts) within the `angular-cli.json` files in the `scripts: []` section.

Then only `import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';` and your error will disappear.

Please note that if you're using `ng serve` you'll have to restart your app to correctly load the script.