# Unable to see Base64 PDF in chrome browser using following code?

Tags: javascript

I am using java script code snippet to view the base64 string pdf that i am able to view in internet explorer and safari but not able to view on Google chrome.
by using following code:

pdfWindow.document.write("");

Comment: what is the error? your question has already answer here [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591430/open-jspdf-created-pdf-in-chromes-new-tab-window/54597529)

Comment: It showing only blank page in chrome where as same code is showing respective file data in other browsers

Answer (score 0):

try jsPDF. it comes with a built-in method pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow'), which uses iframe.