# Losing content when i convert html to pdf with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, jspdf

In my React App (client-side) i have a button to create a pdf using the current html content with **jsPDF**. I'm using **.html()** instead of **.fromHTML()** because i need to keep the html styles in the pdf conversion. **The Real Problem is** when i use **html()** i lost a lot of content for the row/col structure of the page. So, i need to scale my html content into the pdf, but i don't know how to do it.

My code:

```
let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4')
    let source = document.getElementById('pdfContent')

    doc.html( source, {
        callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save();
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "lost a lot of content" if you meant your content cannot fit into an a4 page then you can either make your page larger, say using a3 instead of a4, or you may shrink the content by using `scale` in `html2canvas`. The scale can be calculated based on your page format and element size.

```
let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4')

doc.html(document.getElementById('pdfContent'), {
    html2canvas: {
        scale: [yourScaleHere],
    },
    x: [margin],
    y: [margin],
    callback: function (doc) {
        window.open(doc.output('bloburl'));
    }
});
```

If you don't need a standard page size, you may just set the page according to your content. e.g. `let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [612, 1200]);`

Comment: It works, but now to content starts in the middle of the page. I read that it could be fixed be downgrade html2canvas version to rc1, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try to set the x and y values. Code updated

Comment: Resurrecting and old answer here. "The scale can be calculated based on your page format and element size." do you happen to have an example or formula for doing that?

Comment: @shenn https://stackoverflow.com/a/54847643/4271117

Comment: @WeihuiGuo thanks! I'll reply to you in there, having some issues